# How to override di.xml of core module in custom module Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php-7.3

I want to remove some portion from di.xml of vendor module. Below example of some portion that to be removed.

```
<type name="Magento\Braintree\Block\GooglePay\Shortcut\Button">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Braintree::googlepay/shortcut.phtml</item>
                <item name="alias" xsi:type="string">braintree.googlepay.mini-cart</item>
                <item name="button_id" xsi:type="string">braintree-googlepay-mini-cart</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="payment" xsi:type="object">BraintreeGooglePay</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

How can I remove the it using override of di.xml in custom module.

Comment: Why not remove the button completely? Or do you want to change the arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the possible options.

The solution that did work for me is to make the item inside argument tag to null.
In my scenario, I do not want this item in dependency injection. That works for me.

Below code added in custom module etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Braintree\Block\GooglePay\Shortcut\Button">
     <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="template" xsi:type="null" />
           <item name="alias" xsi:type="null" />
           <item name="button_id" xsi:type="null" />
        </argument>
        <argument name="payment" xsi:type="object">BraintreeGooglePay</argument>
     </arguments>
</type>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting

```
<type name="Magento\Braintree\Block\GooglePay\Shortcut\Button">
    <arguments>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Inside custom `di.xml`?
Then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, so that dependencies are updated.

To remove the button completely, search for occurences of the block class and create own layout file(-s) in custom module (`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/{{THE_LAYOUT_NAME}}.xml`) with following content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="{{GOOGLE_PAY_BUTTON_BLOCK_NAME}}" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

EDIT: The button block name is defined within the layout files by the `name` attribute of `<block>` tag.